# How to read home directory in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, scripting

I'm trying to write a python script that will copy some files into certain directories and then add a source to my `.bash_profile`.  I am having some issues even getting this script off the ground.  I am currently trying to just check if there is a `.bash_profile` and if so read the contents

```
import os.path

def main():
    file_path = '~/.bash_profile'
    file_exists = os.path.isfile(file_path)

    if file_exists:
        print('file exists')
        f = open(file_path, "r")
        if f.mode == "r":
            contents = f.read()
            print(contents)
    else:
        print('file does not exist')

if __name__== "__main__":
    main()
```

if I take my code out of the if statement I receive this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bash_install.py", line 9, in <module>
    main()
  File "bash_install.py", line 3, in main
    f = open('~/.bash_profile', "r")
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '~/.bash_profile'
```

I can't seem to find any information on how to read into the home `~` directory or is this an issue with `.bash_profile` being a hidden file? Any direction would be much appreciated

Comment: What OS are you using? `~` is home not root (on linux based machines). Root is `/`.

Comment: You're looking for *home*, not *root*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to call [`os.path.expanduser(file_path)`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/os.path.html) to expand the path that starts with `~`.

Comment: TIL. Thanks for that.

Comment: Works like a charm. =)

Answer (score 3):

- `~` to get home path from this use `os.path.expanduser` function.

```
import os
f = open(os.path.expanduser('~/.bash_profile') , "r")
```

Answer (score 0):

~ is expanded by the shell, it has no special meaning for python.